# Stuck between augmented reality and video editing

Tags: math, frameworks, gps, video-streaming, augmented-reality

So here is the thing.

I got a camera and elements moving in front of this camera. I know the gps coords. of the camera and of the elements. Now I want to put an overlay on the video, to place tooltips next to the elements. After that I need to stream the enriched video to the clients.

I already tried [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) with an transparent browser layer on top of the camera video, but I failed at the calculations of the right tooltip location. I think this is something somebody already took care of, but I could not find a liberay or framework for this yet.

Did someone already solved a similar Problem ? Or is there a framework for something like this?

Thank's for your help !

Comment: Positions are not enough. You would at least need the camera orientation. And maybe even lens distortion parameters. And even then, relying on GPS coordinates is probably not accurate enough, depending on the scale of your scene.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Wikitude SDK](http://www.wikitude.com/products/wikitude-sdk/) offers what you need. For the streaming part you might need to implement a plugin so that you can send the video stream to the clients